# Mongo Storing filters in document

Tags: mongodb, performance, nosql

I have to store some template data in mongo and restrict the document for age ranges. Example doc below.

```
{
_id: ObjectId("unique123..."),
other data...,
filters : {
   age : {
      min : 18,
      max : 23
   }
},
{
_id: ObjectId("unique234..."),
other data...,
filters : {
   age : {
      min : 20,
      max : 40
   }
}
```

Now I can query all templates for example age 26 with `{ $and : [{"filters.age.min": {$lt : 26}}, {"filters.age.max": {$gt : 26}}] }`.
Is there a more efficient way of storing the document?

Comment: I am not sure, but take a look at this: [Implement Field Level Redaction in MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.0/tutorial/implement-field-level-redaction/index.html).

Comment: IMO, simply store the age at the top level fields. And have the filters templates as your constants (in the language/environment where u are using mongodb e:g: node), and prepare queries based on these filter templates. Takes care of this- you might not want to change the stored data just because at later point in time these filter thresholds got changed to something else.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing a lot about your data model, I can only suggest the following based on my limited knowledge about your document:

- The "filters" nested object seems out of place in your document object. Filters are always going to be set in the query itself, so the target document in the DB should be agnostic of those. It also seems you only have one element inside: age, which seems overkill. Once again I am making an assumption based on provided info.
- If each document needs to have a max and a min age, why not just store them both as "minAge" and "maxAge" at the root level?

Then your query becomes

```
{ $and : [{"minAge": {$lt : 26}}, {"maxAge": {$gt : 26}}] }
```

Comment: Actually I have more filters like age range like allowed cities, rank range etc. so I wanted to store them in a well organised manner for efficient querying.

Comment: Can you please provide some more information regarding your data model and some context on what queries you expect to be running against it?